# How to see full autocomplete method in Javascript by Netbean

Tags: javascript, netbeans, autocomplete

How can I see methods of any Object which defined in HTML tag and is called in JavaScript? Please see my issue as below:

[image]

I want to see method **getContext("2d")** or **other methods of Canvas Object** on autocomplete panel but I did not see any method of Canvas Object display on that.

So hard to remember all of method of any object of HTML, so, what is solution to fix my issue?? Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I think you tried to add an image, which appears here as a broken link. The image seems to be important for understanding, please edit your question and try to add it again.

Comment: yes, but I need at least 10 reputation to post image, so, please see image via link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8C6JL.png, you can see my issue.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks for the hint - I fixed it for you.

Comment: oh, thank you, waiting for answer!